# reading CSV content in ejs

Tags: node.js, csv, d3.js, ejs

I have the following code to fetch a CSV, convert it to a string and pass to my ejs. This works. The CSV has the first row (header) X,Y,time and numbers in consequent rows. What I really need is to be able to fetch values of each parameter (X, Y, time) and use them to draw a graph. How do I do this?

```
d3.csv("http://vhost11.lnu.se:20090/assig2/data1.csv", function (data) {
    var data1 = data;
    console.log(data[0]);
    app.get('/doctor', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
        res.render('doctor.ejs', {
            user: req.user,
            datap1: JSON.stringify(data1)
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Could u plz provide a working fiddle?

Comment: Sorry, I am brand new to programming, don't know what fiddle is...

Answer (score 0):

```
res.render('doctor.ejs', {
   user: req.user,
   datap1: JSON.stringify(data1)
});
```

here as you are sending the datap1 as string to the frontend in EJS Template. You have to make sure to Parse the string data as JSON(Javascript Object Notation). So, that you can access it inside your script tag to apply in GRAPH.

```
 <script>
   var datap1 = JSON.parse(<%datap1%>);
   // now pass datap1 to graph api
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Shishir, but how do I extract X,Y, time columns separately, i tried this in my ejs but this doesn't work. <script>
   var datap1 = JSON.parse(<%datap1%>);
   
</script>
<%= datap1.X%>

Comment: <script>
   var datap1 = JSON.parse(<%datap1%>);
   // now pass datap1 to graph api
  console.log(datap1.X)  // is correct
  console.log(<%datap1.X%>)  // is incorrect
</script>

As, datap1 is on the clientside and not a server side data. So, you dont need to use tags ( <%%> ) for accessing data.